# Where is isolated storage from WP7 emulator located on PC?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, isolatedstorage

When we use simulator and store files in isolated storage. Where is the file actually stored on computer? I mean the path.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20368406/where-is-isolated-storage-from-wp8-emulator-located-on-pcsolved

check this link..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If by "simulator" you mean the emulator then this data is not stored in a "real" folder on the host PC.

The emulator is (for arguments sake) a virtual machine and so has it's entire folder structure stored separately.

On the assumption that you don't just want to know this but rather work with the files in Isolated Storage (as part of your development/testing process) then you should check out [Windows Phone 7 Isolated Storage Explorer](http://wp7explorer.codeplex.com/) which allows you to interact with these files.

If you want to work from the command line (to automate your interaction) then check out [this post by Justin Angel on emulator automation](http://justinangel.net/WindowsPhone7EmulatorAutomation).

Answer (score 1):

It's obscured by design.

The exact location depends on both the application and user so there will be a different location for each user running the same application.

Answer (score 1):

I think I read somewhere that [Silverlight Spy](http://firstfloorsoftware.com/silverlightspy) also lets you inspect isolated storage for WP7 apps. I don't use the tool myself, so I wouldn't know.

Comment: This is correct. Silverlight Spy enables you to view (at least) text and image files that are in Isolated Storage. It's well worth the license costs to get WP7 support :)

Answer (score 1):

The "Mango" SDK ships with the [ISETool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh286408%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) that can take and restore snapshots of an application's isolated storage to/from a local directory:

```
# Copy data from IS to directory
ISETool.exe ts xd <PRODUCT-ID> "C:\TempDirectory\IsolatedStore"

# Copy data from IS to directory
ISETool.exe rs xd <PRODUCT-ID> "C:\TempDirectory\IsolatedStore"
```

Answer (score -1):

Usually, .Net stores it under windows Vista or windows 7 in:

> C:\Users\_user_\AppData\Local\IsolatedStorage

On windows XP:

> C:\Documents and Settings\_user_\Local Settings\Application Data\IsolatedStorage

Both with _user_ the username of the user. Under these folders are completely obscure subdirectories which are created and maintained by the isolated storage API.
I don't know if there is any difference in this on WP7 or Silverlight, but else it is stored here

Comment: In "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local" there is no folder named IsolatedStorage.

Comment: @Vaysage try: C:\Users\{username}\AppData\LocalLow\Microsoft\Silverlight\is

Comment: In Thanks for reply ,but its not storing there :(

Comment: these folder are used by Silvelight when running on a WIndows PC. The question is specifically refering to Windows Phone 7 where the situation is different.