# WP7 -- finding isolatedStorage files on my computer

Tags: c#, visual-studio, silverlight, windows-phone-7, isolatedstorage

I am trying to use the C# class IsolatedStorageFile to write some data to a file in my app.  This is using the simulator.  I would like to look on my computer to see if it worked (i.e., look at the file in notepad).  Where can I find that file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Isolated Storage is stored in the emulator, which is a virtual machine, and not directly on your harddrive. You'll have to code your own file viewer (e.g. from within your app, load the file from Isolated Storage and display the text using StreamReader). 
I vaguely remember that the Mango toolkit (out in May) features an IsolatedStorage viewer built into the emulator, but I'm not sure what features it has.

You might be interested in [this blog post](http://j2i.net/BlogEngine/post/2010/08/24/Getting-to-my-Isolated-Files.aspx). It explains how to export your file to your desktop.

Answer (score 1):

You can download [IsolatedStorageExplorer](http://wp7explorer.codeplex.com/) And use it to download file from IsolatedStorage to Computer.
Check out [this Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5153224/where-is-isolated-storage-from-wp7-emulator-located-on-pc) and Answer given by Matt Lacey